# Django 1.5 Creating multiple instances of model in ModelAdmin

Tags: django, model, admin

I'm kind of puzzled with this task:

I have 2 tables: User, Codes

I want to generate randomly codes in a specific pattern.
I've already written that part as a function, but it's hard to implement the function
in the ModelAdmin.

So I would be very pleased if someone knows a trick to accomplish this.
It would be enough to have a button in the User form to envoke the function, which then creates these codes.

But how do I implement such a button?
Is there a way to to this?

**EDIT:** typo

**SOLUTION:**
Since I want to generate vouchers for a particular user I can edit the **admin.py** like this:

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def vouchers(self, obj):
            return "<a href='%s'>Generate vouchers</a>" % reverse(gen_voucher_view, kwargs={'user':obj.pk,})
    vouchers.allow_tags = True
    list_display = (..., 'vouchers')
```

which represents a clickable link in the admin view of my User model.

Now I connect the link to my view in **urls.py** by adding

```
url(r'admin/gen_vouchers/(?P<user>\w+)/$', gen_voucher_view, name='gen_voucher_view')
```

to urlpatterns.

For creating the vouchers I provide a form in **forms.py**

```
class VoucherGeneratorForm(forms.Form):    
    user = forms.CharField(User, required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    amount = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=500, required=True)
    readonly = ('user', )
```

In **views.py** I'm adding my view function:

```
@login_required
def gen_voucher_view(request, user):
  if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = VoucherGeneratorForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # GENERATE vouchers here by using form.cleaned_data['amount']
        # and user (generate_vouchers is a self defined function)
        vouchers = generate_vouchers(user, form.cleaned_data['amount']
        # set error or info message
        if len(vouchers) == form.cleaned_data['amount']:
            messages.info(request, "Successfully generated %d voucher codes for %s" % (form.cleaned_data['amount'], user))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Something went wrong")
        u = User.objects.get(pk=user)
        form = VoucherGeneratorForm(initial={'user':user}) # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('admin/codes.html', {'request': request, 'user':user, 'form':form, 'userobj': u}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = VoucherGeneratorForm(initial={'user':user}) # An unbound form
```

Last but not least create a template **admin/codes.html** where my form is displayed:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static static %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
    &rsaquo;
    <a href="{% url 'admin:admin_user_changelist' %}">{% trans 'Users' %}</a>
    &rsaquo;
    <a href="{% url 'admin:admin_vouchercode_changelist' %}">{% trans 'Vouchercodes' %}</a>
    &rsaquo;
    Voucher Generator
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<div id="content-main">
{% if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff or userobj and userobj.is_active and userobj.is_staff %}
    <h1 id="generator_title">Generate vouchers for {{user}}</h1>
        <form id="formular_generator" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
           <table>{{ form }}</table>
            <button id="generatebutton" type="submit" name="action" value="generate">Generate</input>
        </form>
{% else %}
    <p>{% trans "You don't have permission to access this site." %}</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% endblock %}
```

Done!

To export them in a pdf I used admin actions, as propsed by Sumeet Dhariwal below.

Comment: Is it a one time thing ?

Comment: no, it should be able to envoke the function from the admin interface at any time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND**:
no that was not what i meant, because I want to generate vouchers for 1 particular user and not for more, but that's a good remark.

Answer (score 0):

U mean that you need to run a script from within the admin ?
If so check out django-admin-tools
http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard.html